# OnClickListener not responinding when in DialogPreference List

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, dialog-preference

I have a dialog preference for the fonts used in my app. The basic layout is a ListView where each row consists of a textView showing a preview of the font, and a radio button that indicates which font is currently selected. I want the user to be able to set the preference by clicking anywhere on the row, but at the moment it only works if the user does not click the radio button. Interestingly, the clicks on the radio button will all be processed once some other input event occurs (scrolling, for instance).

Here is my code:

The XML for the ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/fontStyleListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And Each Row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/radioButton1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Java:

```
public class FontStylePreference extends DialogPreference
{
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from( getContext() );
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( getContext() );

String[] fontStyleEntries = getContext().getResources().getStringArray( R.array.fontstyle_entries );
String[] fontStyleEntryValues = getContext().getResources().getStringArray( R.array.fontstyle_entryValues );

ListView listView;

public FontStylePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
    super( context, attrs );
    }

@Override
protected View onCreateDialogView()
    {
    super.onCreateDialogView();

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) li.inflate( R.layout.fontstylepreference, null );
    listView = (ListView) layout.getChildAt( 0 );

    // Set adapter for contents.

    FontStyleAdapter fontStyleAdapter = new FontStyleAdapter();
    listView.setAdapter( fontStyleAdapter );

    // Set onItemClickListener

    ListViewItemClickListener listener = new ListViewItemClickListener();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener( (android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) listener );

    return layout;
    }

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder)
    {
    builder.setPositiveButton( null, null );

    super.onPrepareDialogBuilder( builder );
    }

class FontStyleAdapter implements ListAdapter
    {
    ArrayList<RelativeLayout> radioTextViewArray = new ArrayList<RelativeLayout>( fontStyleEntries.length );

    /**
     * Constructor for FontStyleAdapter. Initializes contents of adapter.
     */
    public FontStyleAdapter()
        {
        // get current font style so we know which one to check.

        String currFontStyle = sharedPrefs.getString( getContext().getString( R.string.pref_key_font_style ),
            "DejaVuSans" );

        RelativeLayout row;
        TextView textView;
        RadioButton radioButton;

        Typeface typeFace;
        int fontSize = Integer
            .valueOf( sharedPrefs.getString( getContext().getString( R.string.pref_key_font_size ), "14" ) );

        if ( fontSize < 14 )
            {
            fontSize = 14;
            }

        for ( int i = 0; i < fontStyleEntries.length; i++ )
            {
            row = (RelativeLayout) li.inflate( R.layout.fontstylepreference_row, null );

            radioButton = (RadioButton) row.getChildAt( 0 );
            radioButton.setOnClickListener( new RadioButtonClickListener() );
            textView = (TextView) row.getChildAt( 1 );

            // set contents and style of each textView

            textView.setText( fontStyleEntries[i] );
            textView.setTextSize( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT, (float) (fontSize / 2) );
            typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset( getContext().getAssets(), "Fonts/" + fontStyleEntryValues[i]
                + ".ttf" );
            textView.setTypeface( typeFace );

            if ( currFontStyle.equals( fontStyleEntryValues[i] ) )
                {
                radioButton.setChecked( true );
                }

            radioTextViewArray.add( row );
            }
        }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
        {
        return fontStyleEntries.length;
        }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
        {
        return radioTextViewArray.get( position );
        }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
        {
        return radioTextViewArray.get( position ).getId();
        }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
        {
        // Leave this as 0 to indicate we only use one type of view in this
        // list.

        return 0;
        }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
        convertView = radioTextViewArray.get( position );

        int minHeight = (int) (50 * getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        convertView.setMinimumHeight( minHeight );
        return convertView;
        }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
        {
        // Leave this as 1 to indicate we only use one type of view in this
        // list.

        return 1;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
        {
        return false;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
        {
        return radioTextViewArray.isEmpty();
        }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer)
        {
        }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer)
        {
        }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
        {
        return true;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position)
        {
        return true;
        }

    }

class ListViewItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener
    {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
        String font = fontStyleEntryValues[position];

        sharedPrefs.edit().putString( getKey(), font ).commit();

        Dialog dialog = (Dialog) getDialog();

        if ( dialog != null )
            {
            dialog.dismiss();
            }

        }

    }

class RadioButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener
    {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
        {
        int position = listView.getPositionForView( v );

        if ( position != AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION )
            {
            String font = fontStyleEntryValues[position];

            sharedPrefs.edit().putString( getKey(), font ).commit();

            // Check if we can get the dialog. A few times the program has crashed here, maybe
            // because it is already dismissed.

            Dialog dialog = (Dialog) getDialog();
            if ( dialog != null )
                {
                dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem - listview with text and button in row, displayed in DialogPreference, was not clickable (listener for short click on list element didn't respond). Setting

```
android:focusable="false"
```

for button didn't help. However setting

```
myButton.setFocusable(false);
```

in listview adapter code did the trick.